# Deadlock in PortMidi on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, midi

My code is using [PortMidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/) for several years now.
I use it for writing portable C++ code to control an external *MIDI Surface Control* of type [Mackie](http://mackie.com/products/mcu-pro-and-xt-pro).
I use PortMidi latest version: 20101008
Lately we found out that when the control is used exensively on Windows 10 we receive a deadlock. **This happens only on Windows 10**.
When in deadlock state the following thread is stuck:

```
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx
wdmaud!CMIDIOutDevice::WriteEvent
wdmaud!CMIDIOutDevice::PlaySysEx
wdmaud!HwModMessage
wdmaud!dspsL
WINMMBASE!midiMessage
WINMMBASE!midiOutLongMsg
MIDICommunication!winmm_write_flush
MIDICommunication!Pm_WriteSysEx
```

Using debugger I found that code is waiting for an event (not a lock).
***Is anyone aware of PortMidi issues on Windows 10 and/or how to get around it?***

Many thanks, Paz

Comment: Win10 is [known to be troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32553208/17034).  Do make sure you did not lie about it, you will get deadlock if you pass the wrong value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*4 months later...*
While debugging I found out that this problem exists also if you use
[Microsoft MIDI API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757277(v=vs.85).aspx) directly.
Due to this I opened a *Premier Support Call* with Microsoft.
After long time of investigation (four months) Microsoft confirmed that this is a defect in Microsoft WinMM API implementation, which *"...does not properly handle PNP removal..."*.
I was advised that a fix for this will be issued within RS5 timeframe.

*11 months later...*
As part of handling my *Premier Support Call*, Microsoft issued [public KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4460006/midi-device-app-hangs-when-former-midi-api-is-used) to describe this problem.

Comment: Good follow-up!

Comment: Any further updates from Microsoft? I am seeing the same deadlock when using the Mixxx DJ software on Win10, which also uses portmidi.

Comment: @jorenl AFAIK Microsoft did not yet fix MIDI API implementation. Microsoft rep advised me that in order to get a workaround this problem I will need to alternate to WINRT API for MIDI. Please note that WINRT API for MIDI requires you to use Visual-Studio 2017 or higher, which requires Windows-10.